# pyspark: How to use the when statement in pyspark with two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have three pyspark dataframes:

1. transaction (column_names = ['result_3', 'ID')
2. rule_3 (column_names = ['OrderID'])
3. rule_4 (column_names = ['OrderID'])

The transaction table looks something like this:

```
result_3|result_4|ID
0       |0       |11
0       |0       |13 
0       |0       |10 
0       |0       |9 
0       |0       |7
```

The rule_3 table reads:

```
OrderID
13 
9
```

The rule_4 table reads:

```
OrderID
9 
7
```

If an item of rule_3.OrderID also exists in transaction.ID, I would like to set the accompanying element of the column transaction.result_3 to 1.
The same applies analogously to the table result_4.

So the result should look like this:

```
result_3|result_4|ID
0       |0       |11
1       |0       |13 
0       |0       |10 
1       |1       |9 
0       |1       |7
```

If have tried this code line (only with respect to result_3), but it is not working

```
test = transaction.withColumn("result_3", F.when(F.col("ID").isin(rule_3.OrderID), 1).otherwise(0))
```

The error message is:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 
'Resolved attribute(s) OrderID#8 missing from 6#21L,5#20L,8#22L,4#19L,3#18L,ID#23 in operator !Project [3#18L, 4#19L, 5#20L, 6#21L, 8#22L, CASE WHEN ID#23 IN (OrderID#8) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ID#131].;;
!Project [3#18L, 4#19L, 5#20L, 6#21L, 8#22L, CASE WHEN ID#23 IN (OrderID#8) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ID#131]
+- LogicalRDD [3#18L, 4#19L, 5#20L, 6#21L, 8#22L, ID#23], false'
```

Thank you!

UPDATE

It would also be nice to do the same thing in a dynamical way (no working yet):

```
rules = [rule_3, rule_4]
result = transaction.select(F.col("ID").alias("OrderID")
for i in range(2):
   result = result.join(
    rules[i].select(
        "OrderID",
        F.lit(1).alias(str(rules[i])),
    ),
    on="OrderID",
    how="left",
                    )
```

The error message reads :
{ValueError}The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Can you do a `leftsemi` join here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with a simple join.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = transaction.select(
    F.col("ID").alias("OrderID")
).join(
    rule_3.select(
        "OrderID", 
        F.lit(1).alias("result_3"),
    ),
    on="OrderID",
    how="left",
).join(
    rule_4.select(
        "OrderID", 
        F.lit(1).alias("result_4"),
    ),
    on="OrderID",
    how="left",
)

df.select(
    F.coaslesce(
        F.col("result_3"), 
        F.lit(0)
    ).alias("result_3"),
    F.coaslesce(
        F.col("result_4"), 
        F.lit(0)
    ).alias("result_4"),
    F.col("OrderID").alias("ID"),
).show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! The upper part of your answer is already perfect. It is not a problem that the table holds nan if the OrderId's do not match. Now I am trying to do the same thing a little more dynamic. I would like to iterate over a list which holds the names of the rules. I have written down my code under UPDATE inside the actual question. Unfortunately it doesn't work yet. Best regards!

Comment: Ok, it is clear now. str(rules[i]) does not yield the name of the variable as a string :-) Naming the columns the right was solves the problem.